# Where the path of admin/b account in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore

I want to get the path of account admin/b. 
Example : this path of Home's item.

> /sitecore/content/home

How I can do ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Account is not an item.

There are no paths for accounts.

Accounts are stored in the `core` database in `aspnet` membership tables by default.

You can edit accounts using `User Manager` application.

You can find more information in [Edit and manage a user account](https://dev.sitecore.net/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/Security%20and%20administration/Edit%20and%20manage%20a%20user%20account) article.

Comment: Because I'm using Sitecore Mobile SDK thus I want to get the user profile. Can I get and edit them ?

Comment: From what I know, you can't edit accounts using SM SDK. See its documentation https://github.com/Sitecore/sitecore-xamarin-pcl-sdk

Answer (score 0):

What Marek writes you is correct. If you want to open a specific item when an user is log in into sitecore please checked below picture

[image]
On Profile tab choose URL and enter next link :

```
/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content Editor.aspx?la=en&fo={F52A0119-A6C3-4A02-BEA2-5B2AC14A4A46}
```

where fo value is the item id .

Comment: because I'm using Sitecore Mobile SDK it's seem not allow the path as above. Thank you !